# Splitting list in python

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list which I have obtained from a python script. the content of the list goes something like:
The content below is in a file but I loaded it into a list for comparing it to something else. But now I have to split this list such that each new list created contains the complex name with the corresponding number. Hope it is clear now :)

```
d.complex.1
24
25
67
123
764
d.complex.200
23
54
35
64
d.complex.302
.
.
.
```

I want to split this list such that, a new list is created from d.complex.1 to d.complex.2 (excluding d.complex.2) i.e.:

```
d.complex.1
24
25
67
123
764
end of list

>newlist
d.complex.200
23
54
35
64
endoflist
```

Can anyone help me out?
Cheers,
Chavanak

Comment: The example just copies d.complex.1 I think you need to clarify your question

Comment: It's really not clear, is this a list, string, lines from a file?

Comment: @chavanak: Please don't comment on your own question.  It's your question.  You can change the question to make it better.  Please update your question and delete your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> mylist='d.complex.1\n24\n25\n67\n123\n764\nd.complex.200\n23\n54\n35\n64\nd.complex.302'.split("\n")
>>> res=[]
>>> for line in mylist:
...  if line.startswith("d.complex"):
...   res.append([])
...  res[-1].append(line)
... 
>>> res
[['d.complex.1', '24', '25', '67', '123', '764'], ['d.complex.200', '23', '54', '35', '64'], ['d.complex.302']]
```

Comment: A bit of modification to the above code, got it working for me.
Thanks a ton gnibbler :)

Answer (score 0):

without more detailed info and assuming your "list" is in a file.

```
f=0
for line in open("file"):
    if "d.complex.2" in line: break # or exit
    if "d.complex.1" in line:
        f=1
    if f:
        print line.rstrip()
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
d.complex.1
24
25
67
123
764
```